# Web application: site works on IDE and not on a public server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have an old site that I left a few months ago and it worked fine, but I decided not to upload it to a real server because I wasn't sure at the time if it was worth it.

Now I have finally decided what I want to do, so I uploaded the site to a free public server but I get an error that I don't get while launching that site with Visual Studio 2010.

This is the link for one of the pages:

http://aspspider.org/thesamy3/MainPages/AluminumPage.aspx

Where you see the error there is supposed to be an iFrame that shows a photo gallery that I get from Flicker with the Flicker.Net API.

Any ideas why this could have happened now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your webserver have a firewall that prevents it from connecting to remote resources?

Looks like it can't reach `api.flickr.com`.

You can write a test page that does a simple request to test:

```
// Create a new 'Uri' object with the specified string.
Uri myUri =new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");
// Create a new request to the above mentioned URL.    
WebRequest myWebRequest= WebRequest.Create(myUri);
// Assign the response object of 'WebRequest' to a 'WebResponse' variable.
WebResponse myWebResponse= myWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: tried the test and got a the same error [WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.contoso.com']
i guess u are right the host probebly add a new feature i wasnt a ware of. thank u.

Answer (score 4):

> [WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.flickr.com']

Your web host does not allow you to connect to other servers.

Comment: A DNS failure doesn't necessarily mean that outgoing connections are prohibited, but given it's a free ASP.NET hosting service it's very likely they want to prevent abuse, so your evaluation is most likely entirely correct.

Comment: is wierd becuse a few months ago i use the same host with the same files im using now and it worked. i will check it out mybee is a new thing. thanks